# CSS: Force textarea to ocuppy all available area

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a form with an horizontal layout:

```
 <div id="container">
  <label for="ta">description</label>
  <textarea id="ta" name="ta" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>
 </div>
```

The problem is that what I want is the textarea take up all available space that the label leaves in the same line. If I try with *width=100%* it jumps to the next line:

```
div * {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
}
```

Any idea to implement it without assign a fixed space to each tag?

Comment: which browser are you using?  I did this w/chrome on js fiddle and it looks like the text area filled the width fine.  http://jsfiddle.net/N9hvU/

Comment: I only tried with Firefox, but the goal is to be universal :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/4QbMr/

```
<div id="container">
    <label for="ta">description</label>
    <div class="twrap"><textarea id="ta" name="ta" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea></div>
</div>

label {
    float: left
}
.twrap {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 4px 0 12px
}
textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Great! I'll have to add an extra div, but that's not a problem

Comment: @wenLiangcan: There are ways to make it work, but you can just use the `display: table`-based answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6471930/405015

Answer (score 2):

For table-like behaviour with CSS, [`display: table` is your friend](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/Qravb/):

```
#container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
#container label, #container textarea {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
#container textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
}
```

Note that if you specify `cols` and `rows` attributes, they will override your CSS.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/N9hvU/27/

I think this is the behavior you're looking for.  Even though I prefer to use divs/spans for element positioning; tables have the unique behavior (from my experience; don't know if this is in w3 specs or not) of not letting items go onto the next row; regardless of how big they become.

So, by setting the table row width to 100 percent, and the width of the cell w/the text area to 100%, the text area will consume any width available.

```
<div id="container">
    <table>
        <tr style="width:100%;">
            <td>
                <label for="ta">description</label>
            </td>
            <td style="width:100%;">
                <textarea id="ta" name="ta"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Ya, when trying to get elements to render right I usually try and stay away from tables too (unless its for displaying data sets or something); but I don't think you can get the behavior you're looking for, and the elements you're trying to use, without using javascript.

Comment: For table-like behaviour with CSS (and as long as you don't have to support IE6 or 7), use `display: table`.

Answer (score 0):

use a percentage less than 100% and leave out the cols in the textarea.try this http://jsfiddle.net/bingjie2680/Bw4MR/

**update**: try this: http://jsfiddle.net/bingjie2680/Bw4MR/3/  you need to use table to accomplish this job.

Comment: that's no good, you can't predict the label taking 15% of width. The OP wants the `textarea` to take the remaining horizontal space of the line, not take 85% and force the label to take merely 15%.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify width for label.
like

> label{ width: 20%; } textarea{ width:80%; }

I would instead put text for the label in the div and textarea in a different div and float both divs (and specify widths for both as well).

Comment: I'm trying to avoid to do something like this. The goal is to "take up the rest of the space", not assign a fixed space.